# Simplify the complex number $\sqrt[3]{\log_{2-i}(5e^{i\pi/6})}$

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

Can someone express this complex number?
$$\sqrt[3]{\log_{2-i}(5e^{i\frac\pi6})}$$

What I did is tackled the inside of the problem first, using one of the logarithmic property, I did

$$\frac{\log\left(5e^{i\frac\pi6}\right)}{\log(2-i)}$$

I then changed $$2-i$$ to exponential form

$$\sqrt{5} e^{-0.4636i}$$

leaving me with

$$\frac{\log\left(5e^{i\frac\pi6}\right)}{\log\left(\sqrt{5} e^{-0.4636i}\right)}$$

Using another logarithmic property, I got stuck with this

$$\frac{\log(5)+\log\left(e^{i\frac\pi6}\right)}{\log\left(\sqrt{5}\right)+\log\left(e^{-0.4636i}\right)}$$

I don't know how to continue it.

**EDIT**

I went back to my logarithmic properties and forgot the property

$$ \log(m)^n = n \log(m) $$

does it work for?
$$ \log\left(e^{i\frac\pi6}\right) = i\frac\pi6\log(e)$$ and $$ \log\left(e^{-0.4636i}\right) = i(-0.4636)\log(e) $$ ?

Comment: Surround math expressions with $s

Comment: thank you for that

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: you want root of unity, I don't understand your problem.

Comment: why dont you try expressing $5$ and $\sqrt5$ in terms of $e$, as $e^{\ln5}$ and  $e^{\ln \sqrt{5}}$ respectively, and then solve?

Comment: Can't I solve that by simply using $log(5)$ and $log(\sqrt5)$ ?

Comment: Your edit is correct.

Comment: so I could use that, and I'm done with the problem?!